# Is there a workaround for using typeid and typeinfo in different version of g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, g++

My program uses `typeid()` and `typeinfo` to check if the two types is identical at runtime.

The following is a minimal example.

---

**lib.h**

```cpp
#ifndef _ACANE_LIB_H_
#define _ACANE_LIB_H_

#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <tuple>

std::type_index* GetTypeIndex();
const char* GetTypeIndexName();

#endif
```

**lib.cpp**

```cpp
#include "lib.h"

#include <tuple>

std::type_index* GetTypeIndex() {
    return new std::type_index(typeid(std::tuple<int, int>));
}


const char* GetTypeIndexName() {
    return typeid(std::tuple<int, int>).name();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "lib.h"

static std::string Demangle(const char* name) {
  int status = -4;
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
      abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
      std::free
  };
  return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

int main() {
    std::type_index target = std::type_index(typeid(std::tuple<int, int>));
    std::type_index* expected = GetTypeIndex();;
    if (target == *expected) {
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("no\n");
    }

    const char* target_name = typeid(std::tuple<int, int>).name();
    const char* expected_name = GetTypeIndexName();
    if (!strcmp(target_name, expected_name)) {
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("no\n");
        printf("target: %s\nexpected: %s\n", target_name, expected_name);
        std::string s1 = Demangle(target_name), s2 = Demangle(expected_name);
        printf("target: %s\nexpected: %s\n", target_name, expected_name);
        printf("target: %s\nexpected: %s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());
        printf("target: %p\nexpected: %p\n", target_name, expected_name);
    }
}
```

---

I compile the lib.cpp into a static library, and link the main.cpp with it, with the following commands

**build_with_same_compiler.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LIB_CC=/usr/gcc-4.9.4/bin/g++
LIB_AR=/usr/gcc-4.9.4/bin/gcc-ar
EXEC_CC=/usr/gcc-4.9.4/bin/g++
CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11"

set -x

$LIB_CC -fPIC -c lib.cpp -o lib.o -std=c++11 $CXX_FLAGS
$LIB_AR cr libtesttypeinfo.a lib.o

$EXEC_CC -c main.cpp -o main.o $CXX_FLAGS
$EXEC_CC -o main_same main.o -L. -ltesttypeinfo
```

It works as I expected (obviously).

---

But when I compile the static lib and main.cpp with different compiler, it doesn't work. The typeid returns different type_info.

**build_with_different_compiler.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

LIB_CC=/usr/gcc-4.9.4/bin/g++
LIB_AR=/usr/gcc-4.9.4/bin/gcc-ar
# EXEC_CC=/usr/gcc-12.1/bin/g++
EXEC_CC=/usr/bin/g++-7
CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11"

set -x

$LIB_CC -fPIC -c lib.cpp -o lib.o -std=c++11 $CXX_FLAGS
$LIB_AR cr libtesttypeinfo.a lib.o

$EXEC_CC -c main.cpp -o main.o $CXX_FLAGS
$EXEC_CC -o main_diff main.o -L. -ltesttypeinfo
```

The output is

```
no
no
target: St5tupleIJiiEE
expected: St5tupleIIiiEE
target: St5tupleIJiiEE
expected: St5tupleIIiiEE
target: std::tuple<int, int>
expected: std::tuple<int, int>
target: 0x5580ab7a36b8
expected: 0x5580ab7a374d
```

---

In g++4.9.4, the name of `std::tuple<int, int>` is `St5tupleIJiiEE`, while in g++7.5, it's `St5tupleIIiiEE`.

Since the type_info is implementation-defined, is there any workaround and stable method to check type at runtime?

Another question is, `std::any` in C++17 also uses type_info, and how does `std::any` ensure the type_info s always the same between different version of compilers?

Comment: In general, checking types at runtime is a sign of a design problem. What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: *how does std::any ensure the type_info s always the same between different version of compilers* - It absolutely doesn't.

Comment: Don't build different parts of your application with different compilers - just don't. C++ guarantees source level compatibility, not binary compatibility. Some compilers and/or compiler versions *do* guarantee binary compatibility, so check your compiler documentation - but to avoid any issues, just use the same compiler for everything, always.

Comment: @PeteBecker I designed an interface, to set parameter with key-value pair, the key is an std::string, and the value can any type (float, int, std::vector, etc), so I should check the type of value according to the key.

Comment: @Acane -- that just rephrases the question. What is this interface supposed to accomplish? Why does the code need to pass any type whatsoever without knowing until runtime what the type is? Basically, C++ doesn't work that way, and doesn't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference in the mangling of template argument packs. GCC 4.9 defaults to use the `I` prefix (which is incorrect), while GCC 7.5 defaults to use the `J` prefix (which is correct).

In GCC, this mangling can be controlled by `-fabi-version`. You can set this option to the same value on both compilers, to make them use compatible mangling. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fabi-version for more information.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any workaround and stable method to check type at runtime?

No. In fact, typeid, typeinfo and specifically `name()` can return different values every time you run the same program, for the same types.

For a given type, you'll get consistent results during the same program run.

The slate is wiped clean the next time the program runs. All bets are off.

> Another question is, std::any in C++17 also uses type_info, and how does std::any ensure the type_info s always the same between different version of compilers?

It doesn't. It does not need to. All that `std::any` compares are types of objects that are ***created during the same program run***. This is guaranteed to be consistent. There are no facilities of any kind, in `std::any` to save the type of a specific object somewhere, and then fetch it out during a subsequent program run for comparison purposes.

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is asking.  It seems to be about different compilation units in the same process (aka the shared-library problem).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my case.

Inspired from [MediaPipe's `TypeID`](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/framework/tool/type_util.h) , I use address of parameterized template functions to determine the types.

---

Here is the code

**lib.h**

```cpp
#ifndef _ACANE_LIB_H_
#define _ACANE_LIB_H_

#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
void TypeTag();

template <class T>
void TypeTag2() { printf("TypeTag2: GCC %d.%d\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__); }

class TypeID {
public:
    template <class T>
    static TypeID Of() {
        TypeID type_id;
        type_id.get_ = TypeTag<T>;
        type_id.get2_ = TypeTag2<T>;
        type_id.name_mangle_ = typeid(T).name();
        return type_id;
    }

    bool operator== (TypeID another) {
        return another.get_ == get_;
    }

    bool operator< (TypeID another) {
        return another.get_ < get_;
    }

    bool operator!= (TypeID another) {
        return another.get_ != get_;
    }

    const char* name() {
        return name_mangle_;
    }

public:
    decltype(TypeTag<void>)* get_;
    decltype(TypeTag2<void>)* get2_;
    const char* name_mangle_;
};

TypeID GetTypeID();

#endif
```

**lib.cpp**

```cpp
#include "lib.h"

#include <tuple>

template <class T>
void TypeTag() { }

template void TypeTag<std::tuple<int, int>>();

TypeID GetTypeID() {
    return TypeID::Of<std::tuple<int, int>>();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "lib.h"

static std::string Demangle(const char* name) {
  int status = -4;
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
      abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
      std::free
  };
  return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

int main() {
    TypeID target = TypeID::Of<std::tuple<int, int>>();
    TypeID expected = GetTypeID();

    TestABI(std::tuple<int, int>{1, 2});

    if (target == expected) {
        printf("yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("no\n");
        
    }
    printf("get  target: %p\nexpected: %p\n", target.get_, expected.get_);
    printf("get2  target: %p\nexpected: %p\n", target.get2_, expected.get2_);
    target.get2_();
    expected.get2_();
}
```

The output is

```
yes
get  target: 0x40113d
expected: 0x40113d
get2  target: 0x400d8f
expected: 0x40118d
TypeTag2: GCC 12.1
TypeTag2: GCC 4.9
```

In above code, the mangled name of `TypeTag<std::tuple<int, int>>` in gcc 4.9.4 is `_Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIJiiEEEvv`. In 12.1, it's `_Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIIiiEEEvv`.

In `lib.h`, I did not provide an implementation for `TypeTag` function, because C++ guarantees source level compatibility, the linker will link `_Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIIiiEEEvv` to `_Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIJiiEEEvv`, they shared the same address. While the compilers will generate two different versions for `TypeTag2` respectively, which have different address.

I didn't find any specification document for linker on performing this behavior but I observed this by running `nm`.

```
nm main_diff|grep TypeTag
000000000040113d W _Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIIiiEEEvv
000000000040113d W _Z7TypeTagISt5tupleIJiiEEEvv
000000000040118d W _Z8TypeTag2ISt5tupleIIiiEEEvv
0000000000400d8f W _Z8TypeTag2ISt5tupleIJiiEEEvv
```

---

There are still some limitations.

- The function must explicitly or implicitly specified
- Because definition of TypeTag is not presented in header file, any type of unspecified type for TypeTag in library code will cause a linking error (undefined reference to TypeTag<some_type>).